# addEventListener not working on a form - vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am having trouble making a form working on a simple rails project.

The basic idea is to take a name and a date from the form and re-use them on the same page using JS. Il later process the information, determining if it is your birthday, and how many days until your next one.

On the first load of the page in localhost, the JS does not seem to load properly. It doesn't find the form.
i have this message in the console, referring to the form ID:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

If I fill the form a first time, nothing happens.
If I simply refresh the page, or submit the form a second time, the form and the JS work fine. my URI changed to localhost:3000/page to localhost:3000/page?.
I wonder why though, I have put the prevent default on the JS.

I have tried to put a condition on the start of the JS script with a IF the form exists, then do your stuff. I don't have the first console error, but the script still does not work on the first page load.

Thanks for your advices.

The HTML code for the form:

```
    <div class="js-form">
        <form id= "new_test_form">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="username" class="form-label"> Your Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="dateinput" class="form-label">Your birth date</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dateinput">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="results">
    Here will be displayed the results
    </div>
```

and the JS

```
console.log('Hello from My bdtest')

const form2 = document.querySelector("#new_test_form");
const result = document.querySelector(".results"); // CSS id selector

if (form2) {
  form2.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const fn_form = document.querySelector("#username").value
  const age_form = document.querySelector("#dateinput").value
  const nd = new Date(age_form)
  console.log(fn_form);
  console.log(age_form);
  console.log(nd.toDateString());
  result.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<p> Your Name is <strong>${fn_form}</strong></p>` );
  result.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `Your date of birth is ${age_form}` );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the JS loading before your HTML? So JS can't find #new_test_form. Try wrapping your JS code in:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //do work
});
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your input. it got me a little bit further, without solving the issue though. With rails, the navigation to this page is done with turbolinks, a JS feature, to render pages without loading the whole page. So the DOMContentLoaded happens once on the home page, not a second time when arriving on the desired page. Thus,  the first filled form still does not work.

Comment: Turbolinks has its own events: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#installing-javascript-behavior
And below are more Turbolinks events.

Answer (score 0):

thanks [@tihu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15627885/tihu) for contributing.
I got me on the right direction. After digging, I found a little more specific event to listen to :

```
    document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", (event) => {
      console.log("Turbolinks turboed ✌");
    });
```

Now the form works all the time , even on the first page render.